# Dúvida sobre templates usando MVC

Tags: mvc, template

Seguindo as boas praticas do modelo MVC, seria correto uma template evocar outra template? Ou seria essa uma funcionalidade exclusiva de um map ou controller?

Comment: O que você entende por evocar?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss fazer uma chamada por exemplo

Comment: Faço coisas em PHP usando o Smarty templates para camada View, e uso e abuso de includes de uma template na outra, e até herança de views. Tipo template "moldura" em um arquivo usando {block} e as views herdam essa, e includes para partes re-aproveitáveis tipo "barra de compartilhamento"